# even odd program using fork

Tags: c, linux, fork

I write a program for even and odd using fork it is printing even for sometimes and odd for sometimes.Please explain this problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
        int i;
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
                for(i=1;i<50;i++)
                        if(i%2 == 0)
                                printf("even %d\n",i);
        }
        else
        {
                for(i=1;i<50;i++)
                        if(i%2 != 0)
                                printf("odd %d\n",i);
        }
}
```

I am getting output like below:
odd 1
odd 3
odd 5
odd 7
odd 9
odd 11
odd 13
odd 15
odd 17
odd 19
odd 21
odd 23
odd 25
even 2
odd 27
even 4
odd 29
even 6
odd 31
even 8
odd 33
even 10
odd 35
even 12
odd 37
even 14
odd 39
even 16
odd 41
even 18
odd 43
even 20
odd 45
even 22
odd 47
even 24
odd 49
even 26
even 28
even 30
even 32
even 34
even 36
even 38
even 40
even 42
even 44
even 46
even 48

Comment: what is your desiderd output?

Comment: The child prints one thing and the parent another. What exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: As of my knowledge the even numbers set (up to 50) print and after odd numbers up to 50 will print.@Andrea Pollini

Answer (score 0):

After `fork()`, a child process will be created.

The child got the return value 0, and will print even numbers, while the parent got the process id of the child as the return value of `fork()`, and will print odd numbers.

```
        int i;
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
                for(i=1;i<50;i++)
                        if(i%2 == 0)
                                printf("even %d\n",i);
        }
        else
        {
                for(i=1;i<50;i++)
                        if(i%2 != 0)
                                printf("odd %d\n",i);
        }
```

However, the parent and child are two processes, it's hard to determine which runs first.
They may use different CPU cores and thus run parellelly, or just run on the same core.

In fact, when multiple processes run on the same CPU core, there's CPU Scheduling.
Note that a CPU core can't not do 2 things at the same time.

CPU scheduing is the method to determine which process to run at a certain point in time. And usually a process just got a short time to run before interrupted, and then hold on there until the next time it get resources.

The processes which scheduled to work switches very fast (context switch), so as a human you could not feel the process holds when another process is running. It's just like every process runs simultaneously.

Back to your problem, some even numbers are printed out before `odd 49`. For example, there's `odd 25 even 2`, it means the parent process (which want to print odd numbers) was interrupted after printing out `odd 25`. Then the child process got the resource and printed out `even 2` after that.

Every time an odd number followed by an even number is due to the parent got interrupted there. On the other hand, when an odd number is printed after an even number, that's because the child process is interrupted there.

Answer (score 0):

After a successful `fork()`, the parent and child processes will execute essentially simultaneously.  (As another answer points out, this is implemented by rapid context switching between the two.)  Output from these processes can arrive at the output stream at any time.

A comment attached to the question suggests that the expectation was for the child process to complete its `for` loop before the parent process starts to execute its own `for` loop.  For this to happen, an explicit `wait` or `waitpid` call must be executed.  This will cause the parent process to block until the child has exited.

The revised code below shows the inclusion of a `waitpid` call.  See also the output below, containing all the even numbers before the odd numbers.

Other things to note:

- The `printf` output is subject to stdio buffering, but here it is not necessary to call `fflush` explicitly in order to ensure that the even numbers are fully written before the odd ones, because this will be done automatically before the child exits.
- By calling `waitpid`, the parent also collects the exit status of the child via the `int *` pointer that is passed as the second argument.  In the code in the question, `wait` or `waitpid` is never called.  So if the child happens to exit before the parent, then its exit status will be held in the process table (as a "zombie" process) until the parent exits.  In this example, the parent and child process will finish at about the same time, but in general it is good practice to ensure that a parent process that forks a child process executes a subsequent wait call (or does `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);` to indicate to the kernel that the exit status of the child is not required).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
  int i, status;
  pid_t pid;

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0)
    {
      for(i=1;i<50;i++)
        if(i%2 == 0)
          printf("even %d\n",i);
    }
  else
    {
      if (pid > 0)
        pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
      for(i=1;i<50;i++)
        if(i%2 != 0)
          printf("odd %d\n",i);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
even 2
even 4
even 6
even 8
even 10
even 12
even 14
even 16
even 18
even 20
even 22
even 24
even 26
even 28
even 30
even 32
even 34
even 36
even 38
even 40
even 42
even 44
even 46
even 48
odd 1
odd 3
odd 5
odd 7
odd 9
odd 11
odd 13
odd 15
odd 17
odd 19
odd 21
odd 23
odd 25
odd 27
odd 29
odd 31
odd 33
odd 35
odd 37
odd 39
odd 41
odd 43
odd 45
odd 47
odd 49
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation,it is helpful for me